# No puedo cambiar el color del borde un input

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

estoy intando cambiar el color del borde un input, pero a pesar de especificar el color, al seleccionar el input el borde siempre es de color negro. Todos los estilos funcionan, excepto el color del borde al seleccionar un input.
Que puede estar pasando? he utilizado el !important y tampoco me funciona.

Mi código es más amplio pero pondré el resumen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto son los estilos y el formulario que estoy utilizando.

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(5, 1fr) auto auto auto 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

form input,
form select {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  height: 2.125rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  color: #495057;
}

form input:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
}

form input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #3786da;
  border: 1px solid #30567e;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div className="prestamo">
    <label htmlFor="prestamo">Monto del préstamo*</label>
    <input type="number" name="prestamo" id="prestamo" min="0" defaultValue={this.state.prestamo} onChange={this.handlePrestamo} required />
  </div>
  <div className="plazo">
    <label htmlFor="plazo">Plazo*</label>
    <input type="number" name="plazo" id="plazo" min="1" step="1" defaultValue={this.state.plazo} onChange={this.handlePlazo} required />
    <div className="radiolabels">
      <label htmlFor="unidad">Unidad: </label>
      <input type="radio" name="unidad" id="meses" value="meses" onClick={this.handleUnidadPlazo} />
      <label htmlFor="meses">Meses</label>
      <input type="radio" name="unidad" id="años" value="años" onClick={this.handleUnidadPlazo} />
      <label htmlFor="años">Años</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es facil, debes quitar el outline con CSS, te dejo un Ejemplo

```css
#ins
{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="ins">
```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó con esto.